# Managing fragments state

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm having a headache with this.

The scenario is the following:

I have an Activity with a FrameLayout that hosts 4 Fragments.
I don't mind to recreate each time the fragments **except for one** of them.
There is one that I need to keep untouched.

Here is my navigation scheme:

[image: Navigation scheme]

**The fragment I want to keep and not recreate is Frag A**.

In my Activity I have this method for managing the fragments:

```
protected final static int FRAG_A=0;
protected final static int FRAG_B=1;
protected final static int FRAG_C=2;
protected final static int FRAG_D=3;

protected void displayNewFragment(int newFragment)
{
    Fragment fragment=null;
    String tag=null;

    switch(newFragment)
    {
        case FRAG_A:
            tag=FragA.TAG;
            fragment=new FragA();

            break;

        case FRAG_B:
            tag=FragB.TAG;
            fragment=new FragB();

            break;

        case FRAG_C:
            tag=FragC.TAG;
            fragment=new FragC();

            break;

        case FRAG_D:
            tag=FragD.TAG;
            fragment=new FragD();

            break;
    }

    if(fragment!=null)
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container, fragment, tag).commit();
    else
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error creating content (null).");
}
```

This method is called by fragments when I want to switch to another, being `parent` the reference to the activity (Main):

```
parent.displayNewFragment(Main.FRAG_A) // Or FRAG_B, C, D, etc
```

I know that I'm recreating each instance in that method and the previous is destroyed (as I call `replace` in the fragment transaction. This works perfect except for what I'm asking:
**How to prevent destroying FragA and keep its state??**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

please use **addToBackStack** to prvent destroying fragment and keep its state as showing below:-

```
if(fragment!=null)
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container, fragment, tag).addToBackStack("spartacus").commit();
else
    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error creating content (null).");
```

Cheers...!!!
Please let me know if its work for you or not :)

Comment: First, thanks for answer. But it wasn't the solution. I don't want to add the fragment to the BackStack unless absolutely necesary. I ended up setting a global variable referencing the FragA in the Activity, and not reinstantiating it in the method `displayNewFragment`. Then inside the fragment I'm reusing the root view in `onCreateView` and not recreating every time. I'm almost sure that it's not the best solution but for now it's working. I'll keep trying other methods. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

> To manage the fragments in your activity, you need to use
>   FragmentManager. To get it, call getFragmentManager() from your
>   activity.
>
> Some things that you can do with FragmentManager include:

- Get fragments that exist in the activity, with findFragmentById() (for fragments that provide a UI in the activity layout) or
  findFragmentByTag() (for fragments that do or don't provide a UI).
- Pop fragments off the back stack, with popBackStack() (simulating a Back command by the user).
- Register a listener for changes to the back stack, with addOnBackStackChangedListener().